# Passing external parameters to trigger in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, triggers

I was wondering if it's possible to pass an external parameter to a trigger in MySQL. This is my problem:

```
Table1(t1_id, t1_atr, ...)
Table2(t2_id, t2_atr, ...)
Table3(t1_id, t2_id)
```

I want to be able to do an after insert trigger for table "Table1". The trigger itself should insert into "Table3", but I don't know how to pass the "t2_id", which I get programmaticaly, on user input. Something like this:

```
INSERT INTO `Table3`(t1_id, t2_id) VALUES (new.t1_id, t2_id);
```

The "t2_id" is desired external parameter. If there is solution, or another approach, please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Triggers don't accept parameters maybe you should look into a stored procedure.

Comment: it sounds like you just need two `insert` statements